# Как задать цвет statusBar, и при этом оставить его полностью прозрачным при вызове flyout

Tags: c#, android, android-toolbar, maui

Столкнулся с некоторыми сложностями, при разработке приложения на MAUI.
Верстая  макет аналог пользовательского интерфейса похожего на Google Calendar. Возникла сложность с `statusBar`.

**Мой запрос:**

1. Сделать так, чтобы при появлении `flyout menu`, `statusBar` был полностью прозрачным прозрачным (уже реализовано).
2. Сделать так, чтобы на основной странице `statusBar`, имел цвет как у `toolBar`

Я сделал его прозрачным с помощью этого ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73506810/21362268
Объясню, в моем приложении он обязательно должен быть прозрачным, чтобы `flyout menu` не перекрывалось `statusBar`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Если `statusbar` залить цветом как у `toolBar`, то на это будет совсем не тот результат, к которому стремлюсь. [image: Реализация в таком виде недопустима] Однако, если сделать `statusBar` полностью прозрачным, то на главной странице он не будет иметь цвет как у `toolBar`.[image: Текущий вид главной страницы]

Подскажите, как быть в этой ситуации? Чтобы и на главной странице `statusBar` закрасить цветом `toolBar`, и чтобы при вызове `flyout menu`, `statusbar` не перекрывал своим цветом `flyout menu`

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких дней поиска решения, на самых разнообразных ресурсах и форумах на самых разных языках мира, всё таки нашел решение!

Копать нужно было в сторону задания цвета системному фону приложения.

Внес изменения в файл `MainActivity` (для платформы android):
Переписал/создал метод `OnCreate`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 49, 49, 54));
        Window.SetDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(cd);     
    }
```

Установил `navigationBar` и `statusBar` прозрачный цвет, чтобы они отображали родительский (системный) цвет фона. Результат привел на картинках ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]